# handling float action button with bloc

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc, freezed, flutter-freezed

i am created a bottom sheet on click the float action button, which doing two functions.

1-  bottom sheet popup.

2- if the form of bottom sheet is valid when clicked will save data to database.

i am using bloc with freezed. is when i click the float action button i give the bloc true value, once i fill the form and it will be valid on click to the float action button the form will saved to database and the bloc get a value of false. once the button is clicked again while the bottom sheet is opened and the form does not validated, the bottom sheet will reopened all over again "i need to fix this issue". i give the bloc false value when the bottom sheet is closed.

**cubit state:**

```
abstract class HomeState with _$HomeState {
  const factory HomeState({
    required Note inputTextValue,
    required bool isClicked,
    required int radioValue
  }) = AddNewNoteClicked;
  factory HomeState.init() => HomeState(
        inputTextValue: Note(textInput: ''),
        isClicked: false,
        radioValue: 1,
      );
}
```

**the cubit code is:**

```
class HomeCubit extends Cubit<HomeState> {
  HomeCubit() : super(HomeState.init());
  void addNewNoteButton({required bool isClicked}) {
//! true && valid
if (isClicked == true && state.inputTextValue.input.isRight()) {
  //! make it false
  //! save to database
  _database();
  return emit(state.copyWith(isClicked: false));
} else if (isClicked == true && state.inputTextValue.input.isLeft()) {
  
} else {
  return emit(state.copyWith(isClicked: isClicked));
}
```

}
}

**bottom sheet code is:**

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
    return BlocListener<HomeCubit, HomeState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state.isClicked) {
          _scaffoldKey.currentState!
              .showBottomSheet(
                (context) => const AddNewNoteBottomSheet(),
              )
              .closed
              .then((value) {
              context.read<HomeCubit>().addNewNoteButton(isClicked: false);
          });
        }
      },
      child: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          key: _scaffoldKey,
          // add note float action button
          floatingActionButton: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              context.read<HomeCubit>().addNewNoteButton(isClicked: true);
            },
            // for float action button
            // icon shape
            child: Container(
              // add note icon
              child: Icon(
                // state.showSaveIconState ? Icons.save :
                Icons.add,
                color: const Color(whiteColor),
                size: 9.h,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```